# Make Quartz.net user System.text.json for mysql serialization

Tags: c#, mysql, quartz.net, system.text.json

I'm using .net 7 (.net core) project that uses Quarz.net 3.7.0.
The project has various converters configured:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
       //...
    })
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new StringIdConverter());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new UshortIdConverter());
    });
```

that is responsible for converting various id's from an object to a string or an integer. I'm currently using it and it works fine for the api.

I'm registering Quartz like this:

```
        services.AddQuartz(q =>
        {
            q.SetProperty("quartz.serializer.type", "json");
            q.UsePersistentStore(p =>
            {
                p.UseMySql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQL_CONNECTION_STRING"));
            });
        });

        // ASP.NET Core hosting
        services.AddQuartzServer(options =>
        {
            options.AwaitApplicationStarted = true;
            // when shutting down we want jobs to complete gracefully
            options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
        });
```

However, when the job is executing I'm getting the exception:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Common.Domain.Identity.UnitId.

I can see that it is trying to use Newtonsoft, but I would like for it to use the System.Text.Json serializer. I have installed the Quartz.Serialization package and I can see that it has functionality for System.Text.Json:
https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/main/src/Quartz.Serialization.SystemTextJson

How do I configure Quartz to use System.Text.Json and not Newtonsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. 3.x.x only supports Newtonsoft. The System.Text.Json code I found was for version 4

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions/2116